# I still don't get how setTag and getTag works

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've checked other questions here on `setTag` and `getTag`, but I don't get it.
I'm  setting tag here

```
   buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public int GetRandomNumber(int max) {
            int min;
            min = 1;
            int num = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

            return num;
        }

        int RandomIndex;
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int countMax = 40;
            RandomIndex = GetRandomNumber(countMax);


            view.setTag(RandomIndex);


       }

    });
```

And getting tag here

```
buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
                int Index = (Integer)(view.getTag());
                tv1.setText(Index);                    
            }
        });
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException` error, therefore I haven't used the `setTag` correctly..
This is happening in 1 Activity.

Comment: remove "Index" from setTag

Comment: Aren't you setting and getting them on 2 different `View` objects?

Comment: @blackbelt I've tried that, not working.

Comment: @andranikAzizbekyan I tried that just now, still, same error and AndroidStudio is saying that Casting 'view' to 'Button' is redundant

Comment: @KenWolf I don't understand what do you mean by that. Could you explain more please?

Comment: wait, you are setting the tag for buttonA but retriving the tag for buttonB

Comment: @user1816780 have answered in an answer :)

Comment: @blackbelt yes, I shortened the code leaving only what I need. When I push buttonA it gets a random int number(_id) and outputs an information from database, then I need to get exactly that number to buttonB, on that button click it will change one collumn at that row ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ken Wolf's answer tells you why it isn't working. To fix it you can simply make that variable a member variable so it can be accessed anywhere in your `Activity`

```
public class YourClass extends Activity
{
     int RandomIndex;   // initialize variable here

     public void onCreate(...)
     {
          ...
     }

buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public int GetRandomNumber(int max) {
        int min;
        min = 1;
        int num = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

        return num;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        int countMax = 40;
        RandomIndex = GetRandomNumber(countMax);   // set value here
   }

});
```

and use the value here

```
buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(RandomIndex));   // use value here                 
        }
    });
```

Also, to conform with Java naming conventions, you should use mixed-case for your variables so `RandomIndex` would be `randomIndex`. That's just a suggestion that may make life easier if you work with other developers or when people are looking at your code to help you.

Comment: huh, I had my variable RandomIndex declared before onClick method, at first I thought - that should work, but when it didn't, I thought I need to use something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You `setTag()` on a single `View` object, to store some information associated with the `View`

[View.setTag(Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

In your example you are setting the Tag of `ButtonA` and then calling getTag on `ButtonB`. Of course it is empty, you never set a tag on `ButtonB`.

The `View` in the `onClick` is the `View` you are clicking on. In this case you are setting on one view and getting from a different view. It will always be null.

Edit: I think for your purposes just use a class variable to store and retrieve what you want. `getTag()` isn't some magic form of communication between views :)

Comment: How can I then get the tag that I set on buttonA to buttonB?

Comment: Just use a class variable as described by codeMagic - I don't think this is really an appropriate use of tags - they are for storing and retrieving info *about the same view*, not communicating info between views, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call setText with an Integer-Value. By doing this android thinks you want to deliver a ressource-ID (e.g. R.string.mytext which are integer values in your R-Class). Android/Java cannot decide wether you want to display a number or a ressource-String. 
 Just change it to  `tv1.setText("" + Index);` and your integer will be delivered as String to setText()-Method.

Comment: didn't work, earlier I tried writing String.valueOf(Index) in setText too. but it didn't work like this either. My error is at this line: int Index = (Integer) view.getTag();

Comment: Ken Wolf has post the right solution for this. Still String.valueOf(index) is required, too.